# Network programming and multi socket

Tags: multithreading, performance, sockets, networking

I have the idea to dev a gaming server (not a mmo server, but a server that can handle many game instance, like many chess party at the same times)

I was guessing that it could be interesting to manage (for the server) a client repartition on many socket at a time. So is there an interest to do this ?

For Example:

5 game instance on port 1234
5 game instance on port 1235
etc ...

I was thinking about firewall. A firewall will do its job faster on huge traffic on the same port or it could be faster to treat small traffic on many port ? and so on can this behavior could be change on different firewall ? (iptables, other ?)

Can we optimize the bandwith by separate the traffic in multiple socket ? or It doesn't matter and put all the traffic in same socket do the same result ?

Do you think multiport network can give a better latency for the client ?

A security gain? if a issue, not one that could give a root access, is find on a server the hacker could cheat with only few people because the traffic is cloisonned on many different socket?

Do you think it's could bring something that I don't think (not difficulty of programming of course) ?

Thanks you for your response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Separating a traffic does not necessarily improve the performance of the network handling. Just because you're allocating more network resources, it doesn't mean that it's going to improve the overall performance because you'll most likely end up with bottleneck problem. You could have multiple ports but still have performance issue if you only use single thread, and conversely have single port and have really good **proven** performance if you use multiple threads(e.g. thread pool) for that socket( using epoll, kqueue, IOCP etc ). It all depends on how much resource you allocate **overall**. I strongly suggest you to use asynchronous socket for your server, either epoll and kqueue for unix (epoll for linux, kqueue for freeBSD) or IOCP for Windows. They have the best performance period.

Answer (score 1):

My gut feeling is that using a dedicated port per game will slow down a server.  Its better to have a single port, and to denote the game at an application level protocol.

It also limits you to ~64K games and can introduce issues with address reuse.  On the other hand, I can't see what it gains either; to be honest it looks like unnecessary complexity.

I am the author of [hellepoll](https://github.com/williame/hellepoll) so my gut feeling is considered but not authoritative.

Specifying the game at an application level also makes it easier to go in and out of games and a lobby on the same connection, at an application level.

Comment: I don't want to pu a game per port but many game per port. But I wan't to know if put 200 000 game(just an arbitraty exemple) on the same port can change the performence if I put 200 game reparted on 1000 port (again just another arbitrary exemple )

Comment: @EJP for example, accepting, say, n incoming connections on one TCP socket is calling accept() n times and then once more to get AGAIN.  Accepting those n incoming connections on n TCP sockets is calling accept() n times to accept them and n more times to get AGAIN.  I linked to my credentials, this is the kind of thing I have micro-benchmarked.

Comment: I am making the assumption the IO is asynchronous; if you're doing blocking IO in a thread then the cost of the thread switch when nothing more to accept is much higher still

Comment: @Will That doesn't answer my question. Connections have to be accepted no matter which port they come in on, and I don't understand why you are claiming costs for *N* x EAGAIN when the `select()` function is available.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is the question?

You'll need a multiplexing socket system call like [poll](http://linux.die.net/man/2/poll) (or `ppoll` or `pselect`) on Linux.

Your concern might be related to the [C10k problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C10k_problem)

Comment: My question is not about implementation. My question is: separate a traffic for many client on many port could improve the speed and/or latency compare as have all the same traffic in one port? (obviously application is multithreaded, non blocking etc etc ...)